# How to Create Something Like This

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, mkmapview

I am making a restaurant directory for IPhone. I am using the map view frame work in iPhone. Well the pins got cluttered together. That's especially true when a bunch of restaurants are in a mall, for example.

Now my friend suggested that I do something like:

[image]

That looks awesomely cool if only it's possible. Is it?

How to do so? I can recoqnize cluttering. That's easy. But then how do I add number to that logo? Create a bunch of pictures? Then how can I pop a table within map view?

Also I suppose people would expect seeing restaurant detail when pressing the bar and call somebody when pressing the call button. How would I differentiate it? What would be the best way to do all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i get to do something like this i will do like as,

KFC,Burger King ,sushi tel have same address

so while the annotationview clicked i will add subview Custom tableview with custom cell to the view .

here i will construct the data(array) for the tableview according to the comparison of all annotations exact address or the street name here suciman.

or

by compare the lat lang with some limitation comparison

i will make that tableview datasource array.

Answer (score 1):

You can create map overlaps and actually move the UIView pins around... I did something similar for one of my apps (click the image to see the full screenshot and look at the lower right... [Here](http://www.locassa.com/index.php/2011/05/locassa/)). If you remember that the pins etc all all standard views you can actually do anything you like with them....